# Do not show window if the user has closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I created a window that appears when you scroll down and shows you a form to subscribe to the newsletter. I've put a button to close it (`fadeOut()`) and does not reappear if you scroll down or up.

But I would like to make not reappear for a time in any part of the site. Perhaps with cookies, I've seen the plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) but I'm not sure how to implement my code.

This is my code:

```
<div class="conteiner">

  <div class="newspop">
    <button type="button" class="close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> <strong>WE KEEP YOU INFORMED</strong></h4>
    Subscribe to our daily newsletter.
    <!-- Form -->

  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  'use strict';
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".newspop").addClass("popin");

    $(".newspop button.close").on('click', function() {
      $(".newspop").fadeOut();
    });
  } else {
    $(".newspop").removeClass("popin");
  }

});
```

You can see it working in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ra5v4tj/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use window.localStorage...

I've modified your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/bau3fk15/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  'use strict';
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500 && !window.localStorage.getItem('isClosed')) {
    $(".newspop").addClass("popin");

    $(".newspop button.close").on('click', function() {
      $(".newspop").fadeOut();
      window.localStorage.setItem('isClosed', 'true');
    });
  } else {
    $(".newspop").removeClass("popin");
  }

});
```

If you want it based on time then I'd recommend using cookies. You don't even need to use jquery for that.  You can use document.cookie

```
function setClosedCookie(days) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "isClosed = true;" + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}


$(window).scroll(function() {    
  'use strict';
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var isWindowClosed = getCookie('isClosed');

  if (scroll >= 500 && !isWindowClosed) {
    $(".newspop").addClass("popin");

    $(".newspop button.close").on('click', function() {
      $(".newspop").fadeOut();
      setClosedCookie(1);
    });
  } else {
    $(".newspop").removeClass("popin");
  }



});
```

Check out 
https://jsfiddle.net/6Ldt5fs6/1/

Of course days can be changed to hours, minutes, etc...

Comment: I think as cookies work with the server and not use more data than this, we would recommend this method? affect load time? I tried the method with js and seems to work well. Using the method with js, the user would see the window if wiping the cache, right?

Comment: @nicogaldo  Neither localStorage or Cookies are stored server side(besides javascript in this case is not being used as a server side language).  Cookies are stored as tiny text files on the users drive. This will not increase load time.  In regards to wiping their cache, the user would then see the window that is correct.  If this answer works for you please mark it as answered!

Comment: You're right, the two work client side, was confused. Thanks for the help!